# Collect artifacts from different jobs within the same configuration plan in Bamboo Atlassian

Tags: bamboo, cicd, bamboo-artifacts

I have an Atlassian bamboo configuration plan that has multiple stages in it. Each stage has a job and every job generates an artifact of the respective test run. The final stage is supposed to collect the artifacts from the different jobs and publish the combined test results. Is this possible?

How should the results directory path be specified?
Should the artifacts, once generated, be copied into another folder to be available in the final stage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled by creating a dependency, to each artifact, in the last job of the final stage.